# how to replace a layout of html web page from a table to using divs

Tags: html, css

I've had page layout made via an Html table in my home page.

the lay out was fine , though i was reading that tables are not the way to go (SEO and maybe not only that)

so i need to use divs, the layout is as follows 
(i am in RTL Lang /style /direction)

[image]

**My Question is**
Could anyone Try and simplify how to or give an example for a lay out like that

and in more detailed explained :

i think "my life" was so simple, when i had to understand the structure of a table
so, for illustration purpose take this markup:

```
<table>
     <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tr>
     <tr> <td>3</td> <td>4</td> </tr>
</table>
```

here you don't need to think much to analyze that this will be 2 by 2 table

but when it comes to divs i get no results laying them as i plan to 
i would like to know how do i make that simple as it was with a table for me .

2 now that i am trying to achieve that layout via divs (no table involved )
and to make it work so that layout will be Cross Browser,  meaning will look same
at least for the 3 main browsers `IE8&9` / `FF` / `Chrome` (only my preference)

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to implement it yourself at all? Or is this just a "show me teh codez!!!1!" request?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas nice of you to ask that , actually it is a thought bugging me for maybe 8 months of frustration and i did not come to a conclusion yet... maybe there's a theory to understand a methodology

Comment: @LoneXcoder This question is way tooo general :( I did a quick google and found something that may help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2011/08/01/html5-part-1-semantic-markup-and-page-layout.aspx

Comment: In order to switch to `div` based layout, you need to be fairly good with `CSS` especially `float`, `margin`, and `padding`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
I tried hard to make template like what you want.I hope you will like it.See my layout
    by division tag.I am attaching a screen shot as well that is created on the base of 
    my div logic.I think it will be clear for you.

```
<div id="main" >
    <div style="background-color:Blue; text-align:center; ">
    Main banner
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Green; text-align:center; " >
    Top menu
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Gray; text-align:center; width:300px; float:right; height:200px; " >
    Right side menu
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Red; text-align:center; height:200px;" >
    <div style="background-color:Fuchsia; text-align:center; width:300px; float:right; height:100px; ">
    contend2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Lime; text-align:center;height:100px;   ">
     contend1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Aqua; text-align:center; width:300px; float:right; height:100px; ">
    contend4
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Orange; text-align:center;height:100px;   ">
     contend3
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:Silver; text-align:center;   " >
    Footer
    </div>
    </div>


**In case if you want external css then use** 
<div id="main" >
    <div id="mainbanner">
    Main banner
    </div>
    <div id="topmenu" >
    Top menu
    </div>
    <div id="rsm" >
    Right side menu
    </div>
    <div id="maincontend" >
    <div id="c2" >
    contend2
    </div>
    <div id="c1">
     contend1
    </div>
    <div id="c4">
    contend4
    </div>
    <div id="c3">
     contend3
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    Footer
    </div>
    </div>
**CSS................**

#Main   
{
}

#mainbanner
{
    background-color:Blue;
    text-align:center;
}

#topmenu
{
    background-color:Green; 
    text-align:center;
}
#rsm
{
    background-color:Gray; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:300px; 
    float:right; 
    height:200px;
}
#maincontend
{
    background-color:Red; 
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
}
#c2
{
   background-color:Fuchsia; 
   text-align:center; 
   width:300px; 
   float:right; 
   height:100px;  
}
#c1
{
   background-color:Lime; 
   text-align:center;
   height:100px; 
}
#c4
{
    background-color:Aqua; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:300px; 
    float:right; 
    height:100px;
}
#c3
{
    background-color:Orange; 
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
}
#footer
{
    background-color:Silver; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: it's not a big issue..you may create an external css as well..it's very easy..if u want then i can create this work in internal or in external css as well and in this post i am just giving hint to LoneXcoder that how they create a template by division...

Comment: hey thanks for your time and effort !! i wiil use those tests !

Answer (score 2):

You can't ask for complete layouts, but I wrote two tutorials that will definitely help you acquire the skill required to make them: [How to Position in CSS](http://conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/how-to-position-divs-with-css.php) and [Create a Fixed ('Sticky') Footer with CSS](http://conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/how-to-get-100-height-css.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <p>This is the Header</p>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <p>This is the Menu</p>
        </div>
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <div class="row">
            <div>1st block</div>
            <div>2nd block</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div>3rd block</div>
            <div>4th block</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rightcolumn">
            sfsf
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>This is the Footer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uEpmj/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

HTML-Cleaner has a nice feature to replace HTML tables with DIVs: http://www.html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/
Make sure you include the css code supplied.